# Delete all list elements that do not contain a specified string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
mylist1 = [['aaa', 'ababa', '28837u'], ['aaa', 'acacca', '28837u'], ['aaa', 'acacca', '837u'], ['aaa', 'acacca', '287u']]
```

I want to search through `mylist1` and remove any entries that do not contain '28837u', so in essence I want an output list as follows:

```
filteredmylist1 = [['aaa', 'ababa', '28837u'], ['aaa', 'acacca', '28837u']]
```

Ideally the most efficient way to process this as the list contains thousands of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to get the result

```
mylist1 = [['aaa', 'ababa', '28837u'], ['aaa', 'acacca', '28837u'], ['aaa', 'acacca', '837u'], ['aaa', 'acacca', '287u']]

new_list = [lis for lis in mylist1 if '28837u' in lis]

print(new_list)

// [['aaa', 'ababa', '28837u'], ['aaa', 'acacca', '28837u']]
```